# Delete a file or folder using PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

I want to delete the files which are in a particular folder using PowerShell commands, but when I use `Remove-Item $DownloadFilePath* -recurs` (where `$DownloadFilePath` carries the path of the folder) to delete files then it deletes the folder itself and the files which are in its parent folder.
Please let me know the solution to just delete files inside the folder.

Answer (score 1):

And if you only want to remove files but no sub folders you can use:

```
$DownloadFilePath = 'S:\Test\Folder'
Get-ChildItem -Path $DownloadFilePath -File -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

This should delete just the contents of `$DownloadFilePath`:

```
Remove-Item $DownloadFilePath\* -Recurse
```

Comment: I tried that but the error comes and execution of script doesn't stop

Comment: What error, and why would you want the script to stop?